# Convert varchar column to date in SQL

Tags: sql, date, amazon-redshift, varchar

I have a data table with `submitted date` column defined as `varchar`.

The values in the column look like this: "2021-12-02 00:00:00". I want to convert this column to date, how can I do that?

I am using the below query

Select
Cast(submitted_date as date) as [submit_date]
From schemaname.tablename

I am getting the below error

Invalid operation:
“Error converting text to date”

Comment: Which SQL? Can you please tag your DBMS ? Btw, What will you do with it(really need to convert to and then use it somewhere or just display the date portion as '2021-12-02' , eg. indeed as a string )?

Comment: Do you want to alter your table or should it only be converted within a query?

Comment: This is a common problem. Try searching in Stack Overflow, you should find dozens of discussions on this.

Comment: `cast(varcharcolumn as date)`.

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan i am connected to redshift and using Dbeaver to query the data. I am trying to get the difference between submitted date and status change date.

Comment: @HoneyBadger yes there are some solutions online, i did some research but it doesn’t seem to work for me, i am new to SQL.

Comment: If you tried some solutions that didn't work, it would help if you showed what you tried, and why those didn't work. Otherwise people are just going to suggest those same solutions again.

Comment: @HoneyBadger Select cast(submitted_date as date) as [submit_date]

From schema.table

Comment: @user8625135 Please use the [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/72318758/edit) option to add information. Code in comments are not easy to read. Also mention what went wrong with yopur attempts

Comment: That "error converting" error can appear for just one of the records (and then causes the whole command to fail). Try it first with a WHERE clause specifying known-correct dates, to check that the CAST really works. Then try and find the problematic record

Comment: @HansKeﬆing- thank you so much, that is the issue. How can handle the problematic records

Comment: @user8625135 does Redshift have a "TRY_PARSE" function, that doesn't crash on errors but returns a NULL?

Answer (score 0):

There can be multiple issues with a date that can cause this.

One way to possibly check if the data is in the format you're looking for is by using `SIMILAR TO` and either filter it out or debug further

```
SELECT DT
     , CASE
           WHEN DT SIMILAR TO '\\d{1,4}-\\d{1,2}-\\d{1,2}\\s\\d{1,2}:\\d{1,2}:\\d{1,2}' THEN 1
           ELSE NULL
    END AS Flag
FROM (SELECT '2000-08-21 00:00:00' AS DT UNION SELECT '2001-08-21 00:00:00' AS DT UNION SELECT '2001-08-AB' AS DT) x
```

| DT | Flag |
| --- | --- |
| 2000-08-21 00:00:00 | 1 |
| 2001-08-21 00:00:00 | 1 |
| 2001-08-AB | NULL |